# Rasterizing vector layer based on the polygon area in each grid cell

Tags: qgis, python, raster, rasterization

I have a (complicated) WGS84 vector layer, which I would like to rasterize to a target grid based on the total polygon *area* within each target grid cell. The target grid is a non-standard 1/12° resolution curvilinear grid (where I have the coordinates for grid cell corners), but simply performing this rasterization for a regular lat-lon grid would be a decent start.

I am not sure how to do this. The `rasterize` tool in QGIS just extracts vector presence/absence at each grid point. I considered rasterizing the grid at a much higher resolution than what is required and then counting the number of high-resolution grid points within each low-resolution target grid cell, but this is not computationally feasible (there is detail at 10 m scale in the vector layer with global coverage) and would only be an approximate solution anyway. Computing the area of the intersection between each grid cell (polygon) and the vector layer cell-by-cell by return the correct result, but would also be computationally unfeasible in a naive Python implementation (the vector layer is multiple GB in size, and the target grid is global with a resolution of around 1/12°).

Is there any off-the-shelf solution to this problem (ideally using Python and/or QGIS, but am desperate enough to use R).